# have the date validation errors with datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC and Jquery, and I had a form to create a new event for the website. On the date part, I use datepicker to show the calendar and lets user the select a date. my format is:

```
 format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
```

but when I submit the form, it always failed and told me invalid format. I found the problem was when I selected the date March 24, 2016, it set month was 24, and date was 3(means March).

what's going on here, can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1ZEE.png)

[how the dates are formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSvPY.png)

Model:

```
 public SeminarListViewModel()
    {
        Documents = new List<DocumentDisplayViewModel>();
    }

    public string EventID {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Capacity { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public List<DocumentDisplayViewModel> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that your `start date` and `end date` are taking dates as the format 'MM/dd/yyyy' and there isn't a month that is 23 or 24... can you post your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class, over top of the `start date` and `end date` properties add this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; /*put above namespace*/

[Display(Name = "Start Date:")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "End Date:")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, and I post my code. DataFormatString and ApplyFormatInEditMode are right for my code?

Comment: @kcc I saw that you posted your code, thank you.  And they should be.. you already have data annotations in your model so they should work.. i will edit to show you how it should look based off of what you posted

Comment: should I exchange the date format which you provide to {0:dd/MM/yyyy}

Comment: @kcc that is your preference

Comment: I tried, its not working. May be I add the code on wrong place

Comment: @kcc still same error? if so, try with `MM/dd/yyyy`.. also did you get rid of `format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'`?

Comment: yes, still error, my format is dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @kcc okay so change the format to my original post was just to see if it works

Comment: I think the format and the startdate should be as same format, right, and I keep both is dd/MM/yyyy, but still errors.

Comment: @kcc ok so change the format to what I posted to see if that works